# Как победить артефакты свойства filter: greyscale?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, macos

*Внимание!* Данная ошибка воспроизводиться **только** в браузере **Google Chrome** на **MacOS**

Вот код: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBWrmL

```css
.row .item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
}
.row .item img {
  max-width: 200px;
  opacity: .3;
  webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.row .item img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/910/limes-3-1329197.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Возможно кто-то сталкивался и победил это? Или я не в курсе какого-то дополнительного свойства..

На крайний случай подскажите какой-нибудь лёгонький плагин на JS, который делает картинку ч/б, а при наведении "возвращает" цвета :)

Comment: "Возможно кто-то сталкивался и победил это?". С чем? Победил что?

Comment: @mix, в заголовке темы написано же: "Как победить артефакты свойства filter: greyscale?" =)

Comment: Что вас в работе кода не устраивает? Код, который вы написали у меня одинаково работает в Хроме и в Мозиле. Mac OS 10.12 Sierra

Comment: @mix и вы не замечаете никаких "скачков" ч/б по картинкам? И уточните версию хрома, пожалуйста)

Comment: Никакой. Версия 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)

Comment: @mix, а вот это уже интересно! Данная проблема воспроизводится как минимум на двух макбуках про, один 11 года, а второй 16...

Comment: С использованием scss из codepen.io у меня тоже есть скачки, но сам код из вопроса(html + css3) работает на ура.

Comment: @mix и на codepen и тут идеально плавно без скачков работает. arch+chrome54.0. Возможно ли заскринить проблему?)

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/eqzHG0lPigUNjGt15k7rtfstMYnQXR

Comment: @mix, ещё любопытней - проект где нашлась эта проблема использует scss. И ещё три макбука подтвердили проблему. Не сочтите за рекламу, но не затруднит ли вас проверить на проекте? http://project.spoob.ru/wordpress